# What is the valid document for expired BRP?

Tags: uk-visa

What is the valid document to have when we apply for new BRP?

Comment: What visa do you hold related to the expiring BRP? Not sure I understand your question - you don’t have to apply separately for a BRP. You’ll get one automatically if your visa or immigration application is approved. https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits

Comment: I am having ICT dependent visa, current BRP expired we applied for new BRP last month. It will take 8 week to process for new BRP. Untill then what is the official docs for job application

Comment: Please update your question with the missing info.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an outstanding application with the Home Office that was made before your previous immigration permission expired, an employer must get a Positive Verification Notice from the employer checking service.
https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/right-to-work-checks-employer-guidance